# GoogleCodeJam code solves tests but submission gives RE

Tags: python, python-3.5

I've written this code as a part of [this problem](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/0000000000051705/000000000008830b) while practicing for Google Code Jam.

Here's the code I'm submitting

```
def hcf(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return b
    return hcf(b%a, a)

t = int(input().strip())
for i in range(1, t+1):
    n, l = [int(x) for x in input().strip().split()]
    cipher = [int(x) for x in input().strip().split()]
    n = int(hcf(cipher[0], cipher[1]))
    decipher = [cipher[0] // n, n, cipher[1] // n]
    for j in range(2, l):
        decipher.append(cipher[j] // decipher[j])
    key = list(set(decipher))
    key.sort()
    s = "".join([chr(65+key.index(j)) for j in decipher])
    print("Case #{}: {}".format(i, s))
```

This screenshot will show you that a submission with the given sample test data is working.

[Snapshot of test run on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8YjR.png)

However, when I submit the code, there is a runtime error and test cases are skipped. There's a screenshot below.

[Submission Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nG4Z.png)

The website does not show you the actual error message or the test case during which it occurred. Is there something wrong with my code? What can I change?

Comment: are you hitting a time limit? Or your hcf is hitting a stack overflow, so try a loop instead of recursive calls

Comment: i tested your code with an example using much larger N and L and it runs fast. are you sure it is treating it as python3 and not python2?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey yes it's set to python3